# Scope Issue in JavaScript - Cannot Call add of Undefined...

Tags: javascript

When i say...

`table[i].add(deleteButton)` // this works...

// When i call inside an event listener... it's says cannot call add of undefined.

```
imageLogo.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        table[i].add(deleteButton);
    } else {
        imageLogo.backgroundImage = '/images/markHorizontal.png';
        table[i].remove(deleteButton);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need more code.  Where is `i` or `table` declared and initiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've excluded some important code, but I'll assume you're in a `for` loop.

If so, the issue is that each `click` handler you're creating in the loop is referencing the same `i` variable. This is because JavaScript (currently) does not have *block scope*. Only *function scope*.

You need to create a new variable scope for each `i` value in the loop that you want to persist.

```
function add_listener( i ) {
    imageLogo.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            table[i].add(deleteButton);
        } else {
            imageLogo.backgroundImage = '/images/markHorizontal.png';
            table[i].remove(deleteButton);
        }
    });
}

for( var i = 0; i < table.length; i++ ) {

    add_listener( i );

}
```

By invoking a function in the loop, you've created a new variable scope. Because you passed `i` to that function, and created your handler in that function, the `i` that the function references is local to that scope, and will persist.

So when the handler is invoked, it is referring to the `i` that was created in the same variable scope where that particular handler was created.

---

There are other variations on the same concept. For example, you could have the function *return* a function to be used as the handler.

```
function make_listener( i ) {
    return function (e) {
            table[i].add(deleteButton);
        } else {
            imageLogo.backgroundImage = '/images/markHorizontal.png';
            table[i].remove(deleteButton);
        }
    };
}

for( var i = 0; i < table.length; i++ ) {

    imageLogo.addEventListener('click', make_listener( i ) );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't prefixed the declaration to `table` with `var` you can do `window.table[i].add(deleteButton);` since all variables not declared with a var are descendants of `window`